# How to show the upperbound of the Ricci tensor preserved on 3 manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis, ricci-flow, ricci-curvature

So I have more questions coming from Hamilton's "Three-Manifolds with Positive Ricci Curvature" paper [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjy-JOI7cL0AhXS62EKHbtuD0wQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fjournals%2Fjournal-of-differential-geometry%2Fvolume-17%2Fissue-2%2FThree-manifolds-with-positive-Ricci-curvature%2F10.4310%2Fjdg%2F1214436922.full&usg=AOvVaw1Q8Z_FgOvncHlxj0Q5JhfE). I'm working in section 9 on Preserving Positive Ricci Curvature, the proof of Theorem 9.6.

Hamilton want to show if the following hold initially,then this inequality remain unchanged so on. $$R_{ij}\le \beta Rg_{ij}$$ To show it by the tensor maximum principle which got the expression of the top entry eigenvalue in $N_{ij}$ which is$$ \lambda^2(2\lambda-\mu-\nu)-(\mu+\nu)(\mu-\nu)^2=2\lambda^2(\lambda-\mu)+(\lambda^2-\mu^2+\nu^2)(\mu-\nu)$$

Clearly, when $\lambda\ge \mu\ge\nu$, the above expression is non-negative and then follow by maximum principle and done! But Hamilton wants to show its independence of the order of eigenvalue.

After rearrangement, I get two formulas one is from his paper $$\nu^2(\mu-\nu)-(\mu-\lambda)[2\lambda^2+(\lambda+\mu)(\mu-\nu)]$$ and the one  I derived $$\mu^2(\nu-\mu)-(\nu-\lambda)[2\lambda^2-(\lambda+\mu)(\mu-\nu)]$$

Then I am really having a hard time understanding the technique to prove the corresponding eigenvalue is $N_{ij}$ is non-negative at $t=0$.

The best effort I have is I think by using the continuity of $R_{ij}$ s.t assume there exist a time $t_0$ s.t $R_{ij}>\beta Rg_{ij}$. Then extend the upper bound by $\delta$ a little bit s.t exist a a time gap up to $\theta$ then $$\varepsilon Rg_{ij}\le R_{ij}\le (\beta+\delta)Rg_{ij}$$ where $\delta$ will be chosen really small compared to $\beta$ and $\varepsilon$. Then show the eigenvalue of $N_{ij}$ is non-negative. I have no idea about the rest and the logic behind this step.

The result is to show the eigenvalue min which is $$\varepsilon^2(\beta-\frac{1}{3})-\delta[2\beta^2+(2\beta+\delta)(\beta+\delta)]$$ and since $\delta$ is sufficiently compare to $\varepsilon,\beta$ so the above must be positive.

Any constructive thoughts will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your confusion about the sentence "The entry of $N_{ij}$ in question... " on p.282?

Comment: My confusion is his construction of the proof